# Custom Fields - Tab with table

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, datatables

I defined some custom fields with multiple records.
The records are not shown in the data-table.
Open tab in new Window produces an error : DataTables warning: table id=records-4 - Invalid JSON response.

Environment :
civicrm 5.47.1 on Wordpress

Comment: We have the same issue. It does not work for quite a while.
Choosing tab (without table) data is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check in the browser console what is the JSON response? Sometimes there might be a space left out in one of your PHP or template files or print statements which causes a space added to JSON response or illegal output created

Comment: It worked in the past, im not sure after which version the error occurred .
I tried this also in a clean install with the same behavior.
The query is executed as an Ajax call.
if I put query the url direct the browser firefox shows a well formatted json response.